# How to get all the roles present in the mongodb in a database

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I am trying to get all the roles present in the database before creating a new role but when I use the following code it gives me count 0.

I am using mongo DB c# driver to connect to the mongo DB

this should return the roles and 2nd line is the way I am creating the role

```
var collecctions = _db.GetCollection<Role>("roles").ToList(); 
  var createRole = new CommandDocument
                {
                      {
                              "createRole", roleName
                      },
                     {
                              "privileges", new BsonArray
                              {
                                    new BsonDocument
                                       {
                                              {
                                                    "resource", new BsonDocument
                                                    {
                                                             {"db", _customerDBName},
                                                             {"collection", collectionName}
                                                      }
                                               },
                                               {
                                                "actions", new BsonArray {"find"}
                                                }
                                         }
                              }
                     },
                     { "roles",new BsonArray { new BsonDocument { { "role", "read" }, { "db", _customerDBName } } } }
                };
```

But when use *show roles* in the same Database using command prompt it gives me all the roles present in the DB.

Comment: Are you taking about MongoDB's roles, or do you have your own concept of roles? If the former, call `GetRoles()` instead of querying the non-existing Roles collection.

Comment: Yes, MongoDB roles. do you mean _db.GetRoles(). I do not find any method in the mongo C# driver.